# Can I re-establish all my song library from an iPod or iPhone to a new computer?

Tags: iphone, itunes, mp3, music, ipod

I think usually, one iTunes app is associated with an iPod or iPhone, but let's say I got a new computer or installed Windows 7, and now I moved the old computer to the basement, or don't want to boot up the old Windows Vista, or even if that partition is lost, in that case: can I re-establish my song library using the iPod or iPhone that I have?

Because all the songs and videos on the iPod or iPhone is complete, it'd be best if it is possible to somehow re-sync everything to a new computer with the new iTunes app.

Or what if somebody live at home and then have all songs on that computer, and then go to school which is 3 hours of airplane away, or go for a contracting job that also is 3 hours of airplane away, and the iTunes is on the desktop computer back at home... in that case, the re-establishment of the songs can be crucial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can. I use [iDump](http://www.softpedia.com/get/IPOD-TOOLS/Multimedia-IPOD-tools/iDump.shtml) for this purpose. iDump can copy all of your MP3s from your iPod to your PC.

> iDump will allow you transfer your
>   songs off your iPod to a PC, iDump
>   does come wrapped in installer but you
>   can simply drop the .exe in the root
>   directory on your iPod and run it from
>   there.
>
> Connect your iPod and run iDump and
>   you'll have access to all your songs,
>   select the songs you want to transfer
>   then pick a destination directory and
>   how you would like your songs to be
>   named. And then sit back and transfer
>   all the selected songs to the PC.

[image]

Apparently iDump only works for iPods though, and not iPhones.

If you plan to use both, [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/) is probably a better option for you since it now [works with iPhones](http://www.getsharepod.com/help/iphone.aspx):

> **Change**
>   Add and remove music, videos,
>   playlists and artwork on your iPod.
>
> **Backup**
>   Backup all those tracks you
>   just can't lose onto your computer.
>   Import them automatically into your
>   iTunes library.
>
> **Share**
>   SharePod can run straight from
>   the iPod itself, so you can use it at
>   work, school, home - wherever you and
>   your iPod are.

[image]

iDump and SharePod are both freeware.